# Cannot call API within local network

Tags: asp.net

I guarantee this is a duplicate but I cannot find a solution. I simply wanted to test calling the API from another device using postman.

I configured CORS:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options => {
    options.AddPolicy(
        name: "AllowAll",
        builder => {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
        }
    );
});
```

Obviously I used the policy:

```
app.UseCors("AllowAll");
```

I even opened the port used by the API (7134) in my windows firewall.

So what am I missing?

**P.S.** Obviously I did not send the request to localhost but to the correct IP (192.168.178.29)

Comment: What error are you getting? That's critical information you should include in your question.

Comment: I just get a request timeout when sending a request

Answer (score -2):

Remove  `app.UseCors("AllowAll");`

And also

from service dependency.

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options => {
options.AddPolicy(
    name: "AllowAll",
    builder => {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
    }
);});
```

This works for me....

```
app.UseCors(options =>
        {
            options.AllowAnyOrigin();
            options.AllowAnyMethod();
            options.AllowAnyHeader();
            options.AllowCredentials();

        });
```